# Is it possible to have multiple valid BSTs for a given set of data?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Given a set of data in a binary search tree, like the numbers 1 to 10, is it possible for multiple balanced binary search trees to exist?

Or is there just one, unique balanced BST for that set of data?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on the specific binary tree data structure being used, the insertion algorithm, the balancing criteria and the order of insertion, but yes - it's possible to have multiple equivalent and valid balanced BSTs for a given sequence of values.

For example, this is a valid [Red/Black Tree](http://bit.ly/ZnwJC5) where the numbers 1-10 were inserted in ascending order:

[image: Red/Black Tree]

On the other hand, this is a valid [AVL Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), where the numbers 1-10 were inserted exactly in the same order as in the Red/Black Tree:

[image: AVL Tree]

Clearly, the trees are not exactly the same - but the ordering and balancing properties hold for both.

Comment: So, lets say I was using the AVL tree, would there be multiple, AVL trees for the same set of numbers? If so, is the order of insertion the action that causes these different trees to exist?

Comment: @user2305684 if we restrict the tree to a particular implementation, yes we can still get different results depending on the order of the insertions. But we can be sure that if the elements are inserted in the same order for the same data structure and algorithm, the resulting tree will be the same